# Where's the best place to put an icon in a checkmark / label question?

Tags: website-design, forms, icons, page-layout

[image: Checkboxes and icons]

The checkmarks ask what food you want and the clock asks if you want it fast.

Where is the best place for the icons to go in this example?
The icon basically acts like another "yes/no" checkmark.

The options as I see it are the way I have it now, the way I have it now except the icons are at the end of the label instead of being vertically aligned, or the icons go before the label.

I'm looking for suggestions and examples of how this is solved in existing websites.

Comment: See also this older question on a similar problem: [Design pattern for assigning items to two buckets/lists, where items can be in both, one or none](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16770/design-pattern-for-assigning-items-to-two-buckets-lists-where-items-can-be-in-b)

Comment: Hey Ayub, I think this would be a better question for UX, so I'm going to send it over there. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

I might try something where the "fast" options slide in when the item is checked, that way your eye goes to it. I'd also put two choices in so you know that you have to make a choice.

So it might look something like this:

[image: Mockup]

You could probably do without the "normal" option entirely if you think this takes up too much room. A grayed-out "Fast" button should speak for itself.

Comment: I like the use of normal over just toggling fast to selected or unselected because the automatic association of something that is not fast is that it is slow. Labeling the not fast option normal reduces the strength of that association

Answer (score 5):

I can see the first group of checkboxes very clearly, but the second group of icons gets lost. I don't really know if I have to click the clock to do something, like activate it.

I think the second action needs to be clarified in some other way. The straight-forward one would be:

[image]

Possible simplifications, keeping the redundancy:

[image]

None of those are exactly simplified.

The one I would with, personally, would be something like this:

[image]

You could also have a message ('Fast') displaying for a couple of seconds above the icons:

[image]

The icon is there for a quick reference (you can add a tooltip, again with 'Fast'), but still a tickbox is required, so the clock is not just a clock, it's an option.

<sub>Mockups done with [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/)</sub>

Comment: I would go with the first or second options. The clock is entirely unclear and I'd have no way of knowing I'm supposed to interact with it. Better to be redundant than confusing.

Answer (score 1):

keep the interactions together and Labels on one side.

[image]

Comment: The icon isn't for fast delivery - the person is making their own food. What represents someone who needs to make food in a deadline? A clock is reasonable. Also, the second suggestion you make of only showing it if it's ticked is already applied.

Comment: "The checkmarks ask what food you want and the clock asks if you want it fast." Your post misled me :<

A clock is still too generic - it represents time not the rate at which time flows or acceleration, I would recommend you change that icon and use any approach suggested in the answers (as all are valid and good)

Comment: @Ayub You should be using a clock symbol like this - 
FAST: http://thenounproject.com/noun/clock/#icon-No2047
NORMAL: http://thenounproject.com/noun/clock/#icon-No2048
SLOW: http://thenounproject.com/noun/clock/#icon-No2049

Answer (score 0):

Realization and dish types are different search parameters, so they must be separated.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH6Vf4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: The original appears to require one value for 'fast'ness for each of the dishes.

Answer (score 0):

How about having just two buttons next to each dish, labeled Fast | Normal. The buttons can toggle when each is pressed, but if the same button is pressed twice, it clears the choice. For example, clicking Fast highlights it, now if I click Normal - normal gets highlighted and Fast is greyed. Now if I click Normal which is already selected again, it gets unselected. This clears both Fast and Normal this making the dish selection as unchecked.

You can use colors to highlight the selection that would make the choice much clearer to the user.Alternately, use 3 buttons(NONE|Fast|Normal) to make it much clearer to the user.